# Не работает поиск php

Tags: php, html, циклы, input, поиск

Есть код с формой поиска, который должен искать статью по нескольким введённым словам. По одному слову всё спокойно находит, но если напишу второе, то появляется ошибка: **Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\src\news_auth.php on line 105**
105 строка, это строка *"while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>"*. Я пытался исправить, думал, что проблема в кавычках, которые я мог не правильно расставить, но видимо нет. Прошу помочь в решении этой проблемы.
Сам код:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="news_searching"><input type="text" name="search" class="news_search" placeholder="Введите статью">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="news_search_button">
    </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
 <?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $search = explode(" ", $_POST['search']);
  $count = count($search);
  $array = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach($search as $key) {
    $i++;
    if($i < $count) $array[] = "CONCAT (`title`) LIKE '%".$key."%' OR"; else $array[] = "CONCAT (`title`) LIKE '%".$key."%'";
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE ".implode("", $array);
  $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
      while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
        <div class="news_wrapper">
        <img src="<?=$article['picture']?>" alt="" class='news_img'/>
        <div class="news_text">
            <div class="news_title">
              <a href="content_article.php?id_n=<?=$article['id_n']?>"><?=$article['title']?></a>
            </div>
              <div class="news_descr">
                <?=$article['descr']?>
              </div> 
                <div class="news_info">
                  <div class="news_login">
                    <?=$article['login']?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="news_likes">
                  <img src="icons/eye.png" alt="" class="article_eye">
                    <a src="#" alt="" class="button-like">
                    <img src="icons/heart.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                  <?=$article['likes']?>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <?php
      }
      }?>
```

Comment: Сначала попытайтесь понять, **ЧТО** говорит вам ошибка. Читайте [документацию mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php), там есть ответ на ваш вопрос. Не надо гадать, возьмите и поместите её в переводчик.

Comment: Я разобрался, проблема была в том, что в строчке if($i < $count) $array[] = "CONCAT (`title`) LIKE '%".$key."%' OR"; else $array[] = "CONCAT (`title`) LIKE '%".$key."%'"; между OR и " не было пробела. После того, как я поставил его, всё заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в строчке:

```
 if($i < $count) $array[] = "CONCAT (`title`) LIKE '%".$key."%' OR"; else $array[] = "CONCAT (`title`) LIKE '%".$key."%'";
```

И заключалась она, в отсутствии пробела между OR и "(Перед этим я написал перед подключением к бд **mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);**дабы узнать точную причину ошибки, которой оказался неправильный синтаксис.
В итоге эта строка должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
if($i < $count) $array[] = "CONCAT (`title`) LIKE '%".$key."%' OR "; else $array[] = "CONCAT (`title`) LIKE '%".$key."%'";
```